# Eclipse - Dependencies of dependent project in libGDX HTML projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse, html, libgdx

I'm making a game using the LibGDX framework. So I have my core project, let's call it **Game**, and then the 3 launchers project : -desktop, -android & -html. But that's not all.

My core project, **Game**, is also linked to another project, let's call this one **Custom**, which contains generic and easily reusable code that can help me saving time, kind of a personal framework for my LibGDX developments. Everything works fine with the Desktop and the Android version, but when I launch the Html version I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` about the classes that are located in the **Custom** project and which are referenced or inherited by classes from my core project.

I really can't figure out why it works fine on desktop & android, and why I get these errors with the html version.

Comment: How looks your projects dependency? Build path-> configure build path -> projects?

Comment: **Game** has **Custom** as project dependency, and my desktop, android & html projects reference only **Game**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, I had to :

1) Add a *CustomFile.gwt.xml* file in the *src* folder of my **Custom** project with the following text :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <source path="com/name/libgdx" />
</module>
```

`com.name.libgdx` is where all my sub-packages and java sources files are located in my custom project.

2) Add the corresponding `<inherits />` tag in the *GwtDefinition.gwt.xml* file of my **Game-html** project as follows :

```
<inherits name="CustomFile"/> // References Custom/src/CustomFile.gwt.xml
```

Now I have a bit more annoying problem which is GWT doesn't support the `java.lang.Thread` class...